Python pip not working for virtual environment as it is unable to install packages
I am working on a Python flask web app in visual studio. I am using a virtual environment. I installed requirements from requirements.txt by right clicking on the environment and clicking install from requirements.txt. The packages got populated. Now when I try installing requirements.txt I get the following error:
----- Installing '-r C:\Users\shahd\source\repos\TrekkersOrg\ml-api\requirements.txt' -----
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\shahd\source\repos\TrekkersOrg\ml-api\env\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
  File "C:\Users\shahd\source\repos\TrekkersOrg\ml-api\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Users\shahd\source\repos\TrekkersOrg\ml-api\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Users\shahd\source\repos\TrekkersOrg\ml-api\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Users\shahd\source\repos\TrekkersOrg\ml-api\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "C:\Users\shahd\source\repos\TrekkersOrg\ml-api\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "C:\Users\shahd\source\repos\TrekkersOrg\ml-api\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import (
  File "C:\Users\shahd\source\repos\TrekkersOrg\ml-api\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\exceptions.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.models import Request, Response
  File "C:\Users\shahd\source\repos\TrekkersOrg\ml-api\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\shahd\source\repos\TrekkersOrg\ml-api\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import exceptions
  File "C:\Users\shahd\source\repos\TrekkersOrg\ml-api\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\exceptions.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import IncompleteRead as httplib_IncompleteRead
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.urllib3.packages'
----- Failed to install '-r C:\Users\shahd\source\repos\TrekkersOrg\ml-api\requirements.txt' -----

'requirements.txt' failed to install.


Here are a few steps you can try to resolve it:

Recreate the Virtual Environment.

Upgrade pip:try running pip install --upgrade pip.

Clear pip Cache:try running pip cache purge.


Try these steps and see if they resolve the issue.
